# Android makedirs folder creation error

Tags: java, android, directory

Recently I read about folder creation in android and try to implement it in my app. Function should makes dir if it didn't exist, download file from webserver and unzip it. But app can't create folder on external device. Code of the function

```
public static void download(final int section){
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/try2think"); //section"+section);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        if(!folder.mkdirs()) {
            Log.i("Problem", "Problem creating folder");
        }
    }
    File folder1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/try2think", "section"+section);
    if (!folder1.exists()) {
        if(!folder1.mkdirs()) {
            Log.i("Problem", "Problem creating folder");
        }
    }
    String downloadURL = "http://jangofetthd.me/rebus/section" + section+".zip";
    final String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/try2think/section"+section+"/section"+section+".zip";
    Ion.with(Sections.context).load(downloadURL).write(new File(directory))
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<File>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, File file) {
                    try {
                        UnzipFile(new File(directory), new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/try2think/section"+section));
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

What is wrong? I have tryed varient with`File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/try2think/section"+section);`But it also didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the permission to write external storage?

Write into manifest the following code:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application ...
</manifest>
```

You can also look at this interesting guide about saving and reading info from android storages: [Saving Files | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: yes
....
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
....

Comment: just updated the post with an interesting link you can watch about saving/reading external storage in Android. I hope this helps you